# Vercel app works on vercels domain but not for a custom domain, how?

Tags: node.js, deployment, dns, subdomain, vercel

The problem is actually that when I open my website through the domain that vercel automatically creates everything works perfectly, but when I open the website with my custom domain almost everything works by that I mean you can visit all the pages and styles also work. There's also a page where you can send a message and normally you can't send a message if you leave your name or email live, but with my custom domain you can somehow send that and with vercel's domain you can't. i do have to say that there was a bug in my code but then i changed that so i would think it should work with both domains, which is not the case. How come it doesn't work with my custom domain while it works with normal.

I tried removing the domain from the project and then reconnected. I have also tried removing my DNS code at the place where I host the domain and then putting the correct DNS code back on a day later. I have also tried removing the domain completely from vercel and then putting it back on a few minutes later. Unfortunately, none of these things worked.